# how to select option by default in a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

```
<a href="#" class="image-swatch no-lightbox" data-value="red-1" </span>"> 
<a href="#" class="image-swatch no-lightbox" data-value="green-2" </span>">
```

### i tried to add this but didn't work with a href

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.image-swatch').prop('selectedIndex', 1);
});
```

image swatch is plugin for wordpress and have no selected by default option and my only way to do so by adding jquery
so how i can select red by default using jQuery
im not good when its come to coding thanks for your help

Comment: can you share a example of the html element when something is selected?

Comment: <a href="#" class="image-swatch no-lightbox selected" data-value="green-2" </a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, just change the index in $colores[0], 0 is equal to the first element 1 the second and so on

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $colores = $('.image-swatch');
  $($colores[0]).addClass('selected');
});
```